# C# how to chain method execution with an event call back

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I've run into a problem where I need to wait for the call back to be executed before the following line of code is executed in my game.

I have a Media Player which has an event of `MediaEnded` and I want to execute specific code on that event but I also have code after the event and it gets executed straight after the event has finished being added and doesn't wait for the event to finish executing before executing the following line of code.

Media can be from anywhere from 1-second duration to 10/15 seconds.

Some could say I could use the `Action nextScreen` inside of my call back but then I'm not following SOLID / separation of concerns and I don't want my call back to know anything about what is next screen or why it needs to be there it is part of the `HandleIncorrectTap` that's the concerns that this method handles.

Thanks in advance. If you require more code for this problem I can provide more but I don't think more than this is needed.

```
public void HandleIncorrectTap(Action nextScreen)
{
    AudioPlayerSource = IncorrectSound;
    ScreenShaker.ShakeScreen(View);
    PlayWrongSoundWithCallBack(AudioPlayer, IncorrectMediaEnededCallBack); // IncorrectMediaEndedCallBack is the EventHandler in this instance.

    nextScreen.Invoke(); // I need to wait for the event to execute before this line is executed.
}
```

**Update**

FYI: `Actions NextScreen` only contains a check if the game has been completed and goes to the next screen if necessary so I won't be adding that here as it can be replaced with a print statement to see if the correct execution sequence has been done.

Media Element with Event subscription.

```
public void PlayMediaWithSoundWithCallBack(MediaElement mediaElement, EventHandler callBack)
{
    if (mediaElement == null)
        return;

    if (mediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                if (mediaElement.Volume == 0)
                    mediaElement.Volume = 1;
                if (mediaElement.Speed == 0)
                    mediaElement.Speed = 1;
                mediaElement.Play();
            });

            return false;
        });
    }
    else if (mediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                mediaElement.Stop();
                mediaElement.Play();
            });

            return false;
        });
    }

    mediaElement.MediaEnded += callBack;
}
```

BaseViewModel Virtaul and pre-set methods. Contains `RemoveAddedEventHandler` which unsubscribs from the events.

```
protected virtual void CorrectMediaEnededCallBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected virtual void IncorrectMediaEnededCallBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected virtual void EndMediaEnededCallBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void RemoveAddedEvent(MediaElement mediaElement, EventHandler addedCallBackHandler)
{
    mediaElement.MediaEnded -= addedCallBackHandler;
}       

protected void PlayCorrectSoundWithCallBack(MediaElement mediaElement, EventHandler callBack)
{
    if (!Settings.IsCorrectSoundEnabled)
    {
        return; // This right here is also the reason I cannot add Next to the call back method.
    }
    else
    {
        SoundPlayer.PlayMediaWithSoundWithCallBack(mediaElement, callBack);
    }
}

protected void PlayWrongSoundWithCallBack(MediaElement mediaElement, EventHandler callBack)
{
    if (!Settings.IsIncorrectSoundEnabled)
    {
        return; // This right here is also the reason I cannot add Next to the call back method.
    }
    else
    {
        SoundPlayer.PlayMediaWithSoundWithCallBack(mediaElement, callBack);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Some could say I could use the Action nextScreen inside of my call back but then I'm not following SOLID / separation of concerns"_ - TBH I would disagree with this statement.

Comment: @GuruStron could you add the reasoning for that? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pattern of passing next action is widely used in different frameworks and current code does not expose any knowledge about screens, classes and so on. Just rename `nextScreen` to `next` and that's it. Middlewares in ASP.NET Core follow the same pattern.

Comment: As for the question itself - [mre] would be great. And show how the rest of the code looks like. How `HandleIncorrectTap` is added to event list and so on. Note that you should not forget to unsubscribe and it can be potentially hard to do if you will build custom delegate.

Comment: Can you garantuee that IncorrectMediaEnededCallBack is called by PlayWrongSoundWithCallBack in all cases? If not waiting for that might be not what you really want. In any case we need to see more to be of actual help.

Comment: @Ralf I've added time staps and debug.writelines into the code to check the sequence of executions and my `CallBack` method is executed always last no matter what. I can also 100% guarantee that the method is called yes. It is never called if the settings sound is turned off that's the only time it is not called.

Comment: @GuruStron I've added an Update see if it helps.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist according to your code if Settings.IsIncorrectSoundEnabled is disabled you won't call the callback. So waiting for that does not work.

Comment: @Ralf yes so at that point I want to just go next and I do not care. I mostly care when the sound is enabled thats the biggest issue I have.

Comment: So your requirement is call nextScreen() when Media has ended or hasn't started at all?

Comment: @Ralf when the Media has ended.

Comment: Then put next nextScreen into the IncorrectMediaEnededCallBack. Or rather create an anonymous local Callback you hand over to PlayMediaWithSoundWithCallBack that itself then calls nextScreen and IncorrectMediaEnededCallBack in the proper order.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to wait for the call back to be executed before the following line of code is executed in my game.

Just put the code after invoking the callback:

```
...
nextScreen.Invoke();
// code to be executed after nextScreen
```

Delegates are executed synchronously, similar to a regular method call. So anything after the `Invoke()` will be executed after the delegate has completed.

It is possible for the delegate to start some asynchronous work. But if that is the case it has to return something representing the end of that work, for example a `Task`. If that is the case your method could look like:

```
public async Task HandleIncorrectTap(Func<Task> nextScreen)
{
    ...
    await nextScreen(); 
    // code to be executed after nextScreen
}
```